# I'm trying to manipulate a variable in the tooltips section of a chart.js chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm sorry I have to break down and ask but I've scoured every place I can for a better understanding of this.

I have a chart that works fine but I want to tweak the tooltip section in one spot in particular. I have 3 lines graphed. They represent stops, dispatches and hours. In order to display the hours and dispatches to a visually acceptable place on the graph I had to multiply them by 10 and 100 respectively. So it places it on the chart where I want it but I want the hover over tooltip area to have the correct hours and dispatches by dividing it out correctly.

I've researched where to place the code but I can't figure out how to write it correctly. Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated. I'm a novice with javascript (better with PHP) and this is only for the website of the business I own.

Here is my code. I'm using Chart.js v4.2.1:

```
<div>
   <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"></canvas>
</div>

const arrayObjects = [["2023-02-02","889","11",1100,704],["2023-02-03","2282","20",2000,1407],["2023-02-04","2268","20",2000,1298],["2023-02-06","2054","20",2000,1378],["2023-02-07","1890","17",1700,1213],["2023-02-08","1789","16",1600,1156],["2023-02-09","1910","17",1700,1274],["2023-02-10","1761","17",1700,1225],["2023-02-11","1129","12",1200,818],["2023-02-13","1832","17",1700,1194],["2023-02-14","1397","14",1400,995],["2023-02-15","1681","16",1600,1111]];

var datesArray = arrayObjects.map(function(tuple) {
    return tuple[0];
});
var stopsArray = arrayObjects.map(function(tuple) {
    return tuple[1];
});
var dispArray = arrayObjects.map(function(tuple) {
    return tuple[2];
});
var dispamountArray = arrayObjects.map(function(tuple) {
    return tuple[3];
});
var hoursArray = arrayObjects.map(function(tuple) {
    return tuple[4];
});

const weekday = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
// the chart values
var theDispatches = dispamountArray;
var theDates = datesArray;
var theStops = stopsArray;
var theHours = hoursArray;
for (var i = 0; i < theDates.length; i++) {
    
var dateArray = theDates[i].split("-");
var year = dateArray[0];
var month = parseInt(dateArray[1], 10) - 1;
var date = dateArray[2];
var newDate = new Date(year, month, date);
var today = new Date(newDate);
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
md = ' '+mm+'/'+dd;
const d = new Date(newDate);
let theDay = weekday[d.getDay()];
theDates[i] = theDay+md;
}

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: theDates,
    datasets: [{ 
        data: theStops,
        label: "Stops",
        borderColor: "blue",
        fill: false,
        trendlineLinear: {
            colorMin: "blue",
            lineStyle: "dotted|solid",
            width: 2
        }
      },
     { 
        data: theDispatches,
        label: "Dispatches",
        borderColor: "red",
        fill: false
      },
     { 
        data: theHours,
        label: "Hours",
        borderColor: "green",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
        line: {
            tension: 0.5
            }
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Stops per day in timespan selected'
    },
    responsive: false,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
             // I realize the code belongs here
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are on the right track. Did you attempt anything in the `callback` that did not work as expected?

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback

Comment: Yes, I've tried numerous things from posts I've came across. I just can't figure out the method to grab the right variable and whether and how I should loop through it all.